# How to make Webpage to show real time values sent from raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, iot

I am working on a project in which I am using Heartbeat Temperature and ECG Sensor to get the patient data and using Raspberry Pi as Controller; I want to show the values from the sensors to be shown on a web page in real time, values will be in numeric form and an ECG graph. Please suggest a tutorial or method that can help in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Django Channels (aka [Daphne](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html)).

This uses Daphne as a Web Socket Server to handle [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) requests but within the Django Python API.  You get all the benefits, database and templating that Django brings and a simple WebSocket implementation in Python.  A few lines of Javascript and an HTML template finishes the job on the client.
Daphne can also work as a webserver rather than using, e.g. Nginx.  NOTE: Nginx is recommended as this can proxy websocket connections. Neither Apache or Nginx can handle websocket connections themselves (hence Daphne).

In effect you write a simple web page that connects to Daphne using Javascript and transfers data to and from some source to the client's web page with minimal latency and no need to refresh the browser.
It supports multiple connections from many clients and distribution of messages to multiple clients.

Your worker process (running inside Daphne) handle communication with your Raspberry Pi hardware, external API, or shell function.

On the client you can use a Javascript gaming engine such as [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) to draw the graphics in response to data from the websocket, or you can use HTML5 canvas objects to do the same manually.  You could also use a graphing engine such as [d3.js](https://d3js.org/).

See [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Minimal worked example (untested):

```
mkdir django
cd django
django-admin startproject wsproj
cd wsproj
django-admin startapp wsapp
```

***wsproj/wsproj/asgi.py***

```
import os
import re
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wsproj.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

channel_capacity={
    "http.request": 200,
    "http.response!*": 10,
    re.compile(r"^websocket.send\!.+"): 20,
}
```

***wsproj/wsproj/routing.py***

```
from channels.routing import route
from pgwss.consumers import websocket_receive, websocket_connect, websocket_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", websocket_receive, path=r"^/ws"),
    route("websocket.connect", websocket_connect, path=r"^/ws"),
    route("websocket.disconnect", websocket_disconnect, path=r"^/ws"),
]
```

***wsproj/wsproj/setting.py***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'wsapp',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_ipc.IPCChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "pgserver.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

***wsproj/wsapp/consumers.py***

```
from channels import Group

def websocket_receive(message):
    text = message.content.get('text')
    print "Client sent %s" % text
    temperature = getTemperature()

    message.reply_channel.send({"data": "%f" % temperature})

def websocket_disconnect(message):
    Group("ws").discard(message.reply_channel)

def websocket_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group("ws").add(message.reply_channel)

    #Rather than responding to polls from the client in the
    #Receive function (pull). You might create a thread
    #here to handle messages to the client (push)
```

***wsproj/wsapp/views.py***

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse

def counterview(request):
    html = render_to_string('ws.html')

    response = HttpResponse(html)
    return response
```

***wsproj/wsapp/templates/ws.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span id="temperature"></span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            csocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1/ws");
            csocket.onmessage = function(e)
            {
                var myjson = JSON.parse(e.data);
                var temperature = myjson.temperature;
                document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = temperature;

            }

            var i = 0;
            function msg() {
                //Keep sending a poll
                csocket.send(i++);
                timer = setTimeout(msg, 100);
            }

            csocket.onopen = function() {
                msg();
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```